Independent events in probability; counting truth tables
Consider $N=3$ events $A,B,C$.
There are 10 possible statements concerning intersection and conditioning:
The following 4 are logically independent of each other (i.e. it is possible for any combination of them to be true).
1) P(ABC) = P(A)P(B)P(C)
2) P(AB) = P(A)P(B)
3) P(BC) = P(B)P(C)
4) P(AC) = P(A)P(C)

The following conditional statements are not logically independent to the first four statements (and I think they are not logically equivalent with any combination of them either).
5) P(AB|C) = P(A|C)P(B|C)
6) P(BC|A) = P(B|A)P(C|A)
7) P(AC|B) = P(A|B)P(C|B)

The following grouped statements are also not logically independent to the first four statements (and I think they are not logically equivalent with any combination of them either).
8) P(ABC) = P(AB)P(C)
9) P(ABC) = P(AC)P(B)
10) P(ABC) = P(BC)P(A)

Consider all assignments of truth values to all of these statements. Naively, there are $2^{10}$ truth tables, but some of the tables are impossible.

How many possible tables are there?
Is there any formula for computing the number of possible tables for an arbitrary natural number $N$?

